# Javascript - multiple class. How can i distinguish which one was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my simple script, which should place number from span into textarea:

```
function get_post ()
{
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = ">>"+document.getElementById("link").innerHTML;
}

<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<br /><br />No. <a href="#" onClick="get_post();"><span id="link">1948491</span></a>
<br /><br />No. <a href="#" onClick="get_post();"><span id="link">42342342</span></a>
```

But it works only for the first  alement. How can I make it working on multiple elements? Is solution with common id/class good? Or maybe I should add custom id/class for each a or span element?

And final question - how can I change the textarea content without clearing it out? innerHTML is deleting everything I've already typed.

Regards,

Matt

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique, use class instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it only gets the first element is because `id` values are meant to be unique, so you will only ever get the first instance of an element within the DOM.

Using JQuery you can make us of the `this` keyword in order to get the `span` element, like so:

```
$("a.link").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    get_post(this);
});      

function get_post (t)
{
    var link = $(t);
    var textarea = $("#text");
    var span = link.find("span");

    textarea.val(">>" + span.html());
}
```

Make sure you add a class to your links to identify them correctly:

```
<a href="#" class="link">
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/cC9nB/)

Comment: I have pasted exactly the same code as yours and it's not working. Once i click a number it does nothing. I have included jquery lib and there is no errors at all. I have totally no idea why isn't it working.

Comment: @MateuszOsuch: Get rid of your inline event handlers, add your click events with javascript/JQuery in your script

Comment: Check this out:

http://1m3.pl/komentarze/test.php

As i wrote, I have pasted your code 1:1.

Comment: @MateuszOsuch: You have some strange console error, that could be the problem, doesn't seem the JQuery is setup properly.

Comment: so check this out:

http://1m3.pl/komentarze/new.html

Please, tel me where the problem is. There is jquery lib and your script only. And it's not working...

Comment: @MateuszOsuch: I don't know, it must be something to do with the site you are using, it is looking for a resource that I don't think it should be looking for, it certainly not in your code. Why do you try it with this reference: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: Well even ../jquery.js referal is not working, that's why I did this.

I've moved script to another ftp and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

id must be unique in the DOM, if not you get only the first instance, use class to identify multiple elements

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
<br /><br />No. <a href="#" class="link"><span>1948491</span></a>
<br /><br />No. <a href="#" class="link"><span>42342342</span></a>
<script>
$('a.link').click(function() {
$("#text").val($("#text").val() + ">>" + $(this).find('span').html());
return false;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @shadow, you should use a `class` instead of `ID's`. say you are using `link` as `class`. after that following code should work fine:

```
$('.link').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();  // as you are using anchor tag.
  var x= $('#text').val(),
  y = $(this).text();
  $('#text').val(x+y) // if you want previous text too.
  $('#text').val(y) // if you want new text only.
});
```